# Calling another function overload

Tags: c++, templates, boost, overloading, odeint

I am heading to understand `odeint` from `c++ boost` library and I need to know which part does what.
In `boost/numeric/odeint/integrate/integrate_adaptive.hpp`, there is a function called `integrate_adaptive`. This function has a few overloads. The simplified file with my few manipulations is as following:

integrate_adaptive_minimal.hpp

```
#define BOOST_NUMERIC_ODEINT_INTEGRATE_INTEGRATE_ADAPTIVE_HPP_INCLUDED

#include <boost/type_traits/is_same.hpp>

#include <boost/numeric/odeint/stepper/stepper_categories.hpp>
#include <boost/numeric/odeint/integrate/null_observer.hpp>
#include <boost/numeric/odeint/integrate/detail/integrate_adaptive.hpp>
using namespace std;
namespace boost {
namespace numeric {
namespace odeint {


/*
 * the two overloads are needed in order to solve the forwarding problem
 */
template< class Stepper , class System , class State , class Time , class Observer >
size_t integrate_adaptive(
        Stepper stepper , System system , State &start_state ,
        Time start_time , Time end_time , Time dt ,
        Observer observer )
{
    cout<<"type one"<<endl;  //added by me ***************************************
    typedef typename odeint::unwrap_reference< Stepper >::type::stepper_category stepper_category;
    return detail::integrate_adaptive(
            stepper , system , start_state ,
            start_time , end_time , dt ,
            observer , stepper_category() );
    /*
     * Suggestion for a new extendable version:
     *
     * integrator_adaptive< Stepper , System, State , Time , Observer , typename Stepper::stepper_category > integrator;
     * return integrator.run( stepper , system , start_state , start_time , end_time , dt , observer );
     */
}

/**
 * \brief Second version to solve the forwarding problem,
 * can be called with Boost.Range as start_state.
 */
template< class Stepper , class System , class State , class Time , class Observer >
size_t integrate_adaptive(
        Stepper stepper , System system , const State &start_state ,
        Time start_time , Time end_time , Time dt ,
        Observer observer )
{
    cout<<"type two"<<endl;  //added by me ***************************************
    typedef typename odeint::unwrap_reference< Stepper >::type::stepper_category stepper_category;
    return detail::integrate_adaptive(
            stepper , system , start_state ,
            start_time , end_time , dt ,
            observer , stepper_category() );
}


} // namespace odeint
} // namespace numeric
} // namespace boost
```

The difference between these two functions is related to parameter `start_state`. In the second function it contains a `const` keyword. I want to know which overload is called. So, I added a cout in each function. Then I call them from this test file:

minimal.cpp

```
#include "integrate_adaptive_minimal.hpp"
#include <boost/numeric/odeint.hpp>
#include <armadillo>

using namespace arma;
using namespace boost::numeric::odeint;

typedef vec::fixed<2> state_type;

void sys( const state_type &x , state_type &dxdt , const double t)
{
    mat A;
    A<<-1<<0<<endr<<0<<-1;
    mat B;
    B<<1<<endr<<1;

    dxdt=A*x+B*(t>0?1:0);
}

void observer( const state_type &x , const double t )
{
}

typedef runge_kutta_dopri5<state_type> stepper_type;

int main()
{
    state_type x;
    x(0) = 0.0;
    x(1) = 0.0;
    integrate_adaptive(make_controlled(1E-10,1E-10,stepper_type()),
                        sys,x,0.0,11.0,0.1,observer);
    return 0;
}
```

When I compile and run:

```
g++ -std=c++11 minimal.cpp  -larmadillo -lboost_thread -lboost_filesystem -lboost_system -Wfatal-errors

./a.out
```

The result shows that the first function `integrate_adaptive` is called which does not have `const`. Now, I want to know how is the proper way of calling the second function? The object x cannot be `const`!

If somebody even know about the mechanism of `boost` library, telling me the advantage of the second function is appreciated.

**Update:**

original code: [github](https://github.com/boostorg/odeint/blob/master/include/boost/numeric/odeint/integrate/integrate_adaptive.hpp), [doc](http://headmyshoulder.github.io/odeint-v2/doc/index.html)

Comment: Add `state_type const cx = x;` and then use `cx` instead of `x` in the call to `integrate_adaptive`. You can also initialize `cx` directly by calling a `vec::fixex<2>` constructor ... something like `state_type const cx(0.0, 0.0);`

Comment: "The result shows". Frankly, I don't see any result and I don't think that's because I'm doing it wrong. What result are you referring to?

Comment: @sehe `cout<<"type one"<<endl;  //added by me`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The state itself will be mutated. So passing a real const object which can not be mutated at all can not be passed to integrate adaptive. The const overload is here for allowing the creation of the state within the call of integrate_adaptive. As sehe already mentioned, it is possible to call integrate adaptive like

```
integrate_adaptive( stepper , system , make_pair( a.begin() , a.begin() + 3 ) , t0 , t1 , dt , obs );
```

Here, the state is range of three elements packed into a range. Without the second overload one needs to write

```
auto r = make_pair( a.begin() , a.begin() + 3 );    //  Without auto the type will be really complicated.
integrate_adaptive( stepper , system , r , t0 , t1 , dt , obs );
```

In pre C++11 times, the type of the `r` is really complicated, something like `pair< vector< double >::iterator , vector< double >::iterator >` and introducing the second overload simplifies a lot. Most of the steppers `do_step` methods have also similar overloads.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation of my thought. It looks like you have some experience with the library (which I don't) so that's a welcome confirmation. +1

Comment: @sehe headmyshoulder seems to be the author of this library.

Comment: Yeah, I am one of the authors :)

Answer (score 2):

To be honest, I'm a bit confused about the premise of the question.

`integrate_adaptive` ends up calling that `odeint::copy` (from odeint/util/copy.hpp) from `controlled_step_result try_step(System, const StateInOut&x, time_type&, time_type&)`. The documentation here states (among others)

> - `\param` system The system function to solve, hence the r.h.s. of the ODE. It must fulfill the `Simple System` concept.
> - `\param` x The state of the ODE which should be solved. ***Overwritten if***
>     ***the step is successful***. Can be a boost range.

I simply don't think you want a const state. Because the function couldn't possibly fulfill it's promise if the state was, actually, const.

I'd assume the overload exists to accomodate state objects that represent mutable state even when `const`. This seems weird but could be conceivable with a `double * const&` (as opposed to `double const* const&`), if you will.

**UPDATE**

The documentation says for the const overloads:

```
/*
* the two overloads are needed in order to solve the forwarding problem
*/
```

Also, it says

```
/**
* \brief Second version to solve the forwarding problem,
* can be called with Boost.Range as start_state.
*/
```

So, indeed it could be just to allow calling with `boost::make_iterator_range(a,b)` where the Boost Range object itself would be a temporary (bound to `const&`) and the iterators still mutable.

---

Off topic:

In case you **did** want to pass it as const, here's how you'd do it (of course it doesn't compile for the reasons mentioned above):

```
state_type const x { 0, 0 };
integrate_adaptive(make_controlled(1E-10, 1E-10, stepper_type()), sys, x, 0.0, 11.0, 0.1/*, observer*/);
```

Or even

```
integrate_adaptive(make_controlled(1E-10, 1E-10, stepper_type()), sys, 
                 state_type { 0.0, 0.0 }, 0.0, 11.0, 0.1/*, observer*/);
```

Comment: Found some more evidence that indeed the overloads are meant for logically mutable state wrappers (where the wrappers are `const&` temporaries)

Answer (score 0):

You need only to cast `x` as `const` as you call integrate_adaptive():

```
integrate_adaptive(make_controlled(1E-10,1E-10,stepper_type()),
                        sys, const_cast<const state_type &>(x),0.0,11.0,0.1,observer);
```

The const version of the function promises that it will not modify the contents of x during its scope, but `main()` can continue modifying it after `integrate_adaptive()` returns.

(The advantage of using the C++-style `const_cast` is to catch yourself sooner if you ever decide to change the type of x to some other class.)

Comment: Seems `const_cast<const state_type &>(x)` causing so many errors: `In instantiation of ‘_OI std::__copy_move_a(_II, _II, _OI) [with bool _IsMove = false; _II = const double*; _OI = const double*]` in addition to an avalanche of other errors

Comment: Yes, this will not work. integrate_adaptive modifies the state.

Comment: No worries; I don't have the declaration of detail::integrate_adaptive() handy, but if it can't take a const reference either, at least the compiler will tell you! :-)